Problem embedding qquickview into qlayout
I'm using multi-threaded opengl in my qml so qquickwidget is not an option, when I use qwidget::createwindowcontainer to manage qquickview and embed it into qlayout it works fine .
but if I take it out of qlayout , when put back into qlayout, the qml does not display anything. I tried setting qapplication::AA_ShareOpenGLContexts flag and setting qquickview
view->setPersistentOpenGLContext(true); 
view->setPersistentSceneGraph(true); 

but still can't avoid this problem
i want to  re-put qwidget that create by qwidget::createwindowcontainer into to a qlayout and it still works.
